# Not able to delete a row in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

When I am trying to delete a row, I get exception saying-

> large object does not exist

Here is the screenshot on row delete operation,

[image]

There is a trigger that is called before any row delete,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lo_manage()
  RETURNS trigger AS
'$libdir/lo', 'lo_manage'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE
  COST 1;
```

Can anyone know the purpose of this trigger and how it is causing the exception on delete?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo.html

Comment: sure, I read the documentation that has some useful information about the OID and the purpose of using it. But I couldn't find that how to get rid of this exception or where can I find the associated BLOB in the system.

Comment: `select count(*) from pg_largeobject where loid = 14AndTheRestOfId`

Comment: count is 0. Is this the cause of that exception? I just dumped the data from other database.

Comment: yes - it is the problem. how did you dump it?.. what command?..

Comment: check out this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/postgresql-partial-dump-of-large-orbjects-pg-largeobject-table

Comment: No command. I have pgAdmin III and it can do it by right click on table and click on backup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130688/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-my-god).

Comment: @MyGod: In the pgAdmin Backup form, on the "Dump Options #1" tab, tick the "Blobs" checkbox.